# An ordered field with a infinitesimal element elementarily equivalent to the reals

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L} := \{0, 1, +, -, \cdot, \leq \}$ be a language, where $0, 1$ are constants and $+, -, \cdot$ are binary functions and $\leq$ is a binary relation.

We consider the ordered fields in this language. An element $\varepsilon$ is said to be *infinitesimal* if $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{n}$ for all integers $n \geq 1$.

The exercise is now the following: Show the existence of an ordered field $K$ such that $K$ admits an infinitesimal element and is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbf{R}$.

First I thought it might be good to mimic the construction of the hyperreals, but I do not know whether they are elementarily equivalent to $\mathbf{R}$ and the construction looks quite lengthy.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to start the proof?

Thanks!

Comment: completeness or compactness theorem is your friend - take all the formulas that are true for $\Bbb R$ (the formulas are allowed to use elements of $\Bbb R$), add a new constant $\epsilon$ to your language, and for every $n$ add the axiom $0<\epsilon<1/n$, and see that either of those theorems implies that this set of formulas has a model.

Comment: I think I see how I can prove the existence of an ordered field $K$ with an infinitesimal element from your comment. But how can I show it is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbf{R}$? The theory of ordered fields isn't complete, for $\mathbf{Q}$ doesn't satisfy the formula $\exists x (x \cdot x = 2)$, but $\mathbf{R}$ does, right? So I should find an $\omega$-isomorphism between $K$ and $\mathbf{R}$, but where do I map $\varepsilon$ to?

Comment: @Steven Don't just start with the theory of ordered fields and apply compactness, instead start with the complete theory of $\mathbb{R}$. Any model of this theory is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$. (This theory has a name: RCF, the theory of real closed fields.)

Comment: Oh, well that's quite smart! :)

Comment: The field of [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) over any RCF (e.g., any real closed subfield of $\Bbb{R}$) offers an alternative approach with a "more constructive" feel.

Answer (score 3):

After the very helpful discussion in the comments, I will try and put a whole answer here (if any of the commenters want to post an answer, please do so and I'll accept it):

Let $\mathcal{L}' := \mathcal{L} \cup \{ \varepsilon \}$ with $\varepsilon$ a constant. Let $T' := Th(\mathbf{R}) \cup \{ 0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{n} \}$.

We use the compactness theorem: A theory $T$ is consistent if and only if every finite subset of $T$ is consistent.

Let $T_0$ be a finite subset of $T'$. There is a $N \geq 1$ such that for any axiom $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{n} \in T_0$ we must have $n \leq N$. The reals form a model of $T_0$ (they clearly satisfy the axioms of $T$ and for $\varepsilon$ take $\frac{1}{N  +1}$).

By the compactness theorem $T'$ is consistent. Thus there exists a model $K$ for $T'$.

A fortiori $K \models T$ for $K$ viewed as an $\mathcal{L}$-structure and $Th(\mathbf{R}) \subset Th(K)$. Let $F \in Th(K)$. We have $\mathbf{R} \models F$ or $\mathbf{R} \models \neg F$. But if $\mathbf{R} \models \neg F$, then $\neg F \in Th(K)$. This is of course a contradiction, hence $Th(\mathbf{R}) = Th(K)$.

**Added:** I found this math overflow link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39504/what-are-examples-of-ordered-fields-that-do-not-have-the-archimedean-property, which gives the explicit example $\mathbf{R}(X)$ for an ordered field with infinitesimal element $\frac{1}{X}$.

Comment: This is correct. In your addendum, note that $\mathbb{R}(X)$ is not elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As Alex points out, $\Bbb{R}(X)$ does not answer your question. If you want a more explicit example than the ones produced by the compactness theorem, take Puiseux series over $\Bbb{R}$ (see the link in my comment on the question).

Comment: @Steven You should revise your last paragraph. You want to show that $Th(\mathbf{R}) = Th(K)\dots \qquad$ **in the language $\mathcal{L}$**. But this is obvious since, as you say, $Th(\mathbf{R}) \subset Th(K)$

Answer (score 1):

Ordered fields elementarily equivalent to the reals are called [*real closed fields*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field).

Any ordered field $F$ has a *real closure* $F^r$ which is an algebraic extension that is real closed.

So, if you let $F$ be any non-archimedean ordered field, then $F^r$ is an example.

A standard, explicit construction of examples is that if $F$ is any real closed field, then so is the field of [*Puiseux series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) over $F$.

The field of Puiseux series over $F$ is the real closure of the field $F((t))$ of Laurent series over $F$, ordered so that $t$ is a positive infinitesimal.

Comment: This is nice because it gives the minimal solution to the OP's question: Puiseux series over real algebraic numbers.

Comment: @nombre: There's an even smaller example: the subfield of those Puiseux series that are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}^r(t)$. (and this is the smallest)

Comment: That's what I had in mind and I got confused. Is there a description of this real closure?